# When Authorization is Required, Fedora is asking me for the password for the wong user's password

Tags: fedora, gnome, software-rec

I have a shared Fedora machine.  There are two of us.  I'm Bob and she's Mary. (pretend names)  Forever and a day, when I am logged in and attempt to install something with the application called "Software", the OS would prompt me for my password and then proceed with the install.  All of a sudden (I think there was a recent update) it now asks me for Mary's password instead.  Mary is not logged in.  I'm Bob.  Why is it asking me for Mary's password and not mine?

Other Details:

- At the command line, when I do `dnf install <blah>` it properly asks
  me for my password, not Mary's.
- When I write `whoami`, it says I'm Bob, which is correct.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This somewhat resembles this [Server Fault Question](https://serverfault.com/questions/841306/authentication-is-required-to-manage-system-services-or-units/841315), but it is not entirely the same.

Apparently, the Polkit Authorization Manager is configured so that Mary is the administrative user, and you are not. See the [Polkit man page](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/polkit/docs/latest/polkit.8.html) especially for information on in which files it is configured in. Is Mary in some group (like "wheel" or "admin") which you are not in?

Comment: That was it. Somehow my account was no longer in the wheel group anymore but Mary was. It must have been picking her account for admin things. I wonder what happens if there are multiple admins. (experiment time!)